# Kohana 3 simple relations

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3, sql

I'm trying to write a very simple cms (for learning purposes) in kohana 3 web framework.
I have my db schemas and i want to map it to ORM but i have problems with relations.

Schemas:[articles](http://wstaw.org/w/5zp/) and [categories](http://wstaw.org/w/5zq/)

One article has one category. One category might has many articles of course.

I think it is has_one relationship in article table.(?)

Now php code. I need to create application/classes/models/article.php first, yes?

```
class Model_Article extends ORM
{
    protected // and i am not sure what i suppose to write here       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Model_Article extends ORM{

 protected $_belongs_to = array
 (
  'category'  => array(), // This automatically sets foreign_key to category_id and model to Model_Category (Model_$alias)
 );

}

class Model_Category extends ORM{

 protected $_has_many = array
 (
  'articles' => array(), // This automatically sets foreign_key to be category_id and model to Model_Article (Model_$alias_singular)
 );

}
```

You can also manually define the relation ;

```
'articles' => array('model'=>'article','foreign_key'=>'category_id');
```

[More about Kohana 3 ORM](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.orm)

[More about Kohana ORM naming conventions](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/starting#orm_conventions)